# create a custom JS directory in brunch.io

Tags: javascript, architecture, coffeescript, brunch

In [**brunch.io**](http://brunch.io), the application contains two directories that get compiled.  These are controlled in your brunch config file, like so:

```
javascripts:
  defaultExtension: 'coffee'
  joinTo:
    'javascripts/app.js': /^app/
    'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/
```

I am wondering if it is possible to create a namespace along side of app.js/vendor.js and if so, how I would do that.  I tried adding a directory next to app/vendor called `namespace/`, which contains the CoffeeScript files i want to compile. as well as adding this to the config file...

```
'javascripts/namespace.js': /^namespace/
```

1. **Can this be done?**
2. **If so, where am i going wrong?**

---

### UPDATE

there is a `./public/namespace/` being created with my `namespace.coffee` file.  it appears this is just not registering w/ the watcher? or...?

Comment: It should work fine. Have you checked that `namespace.js` file is indeed not being created in `public/javascripts` directory?

Comment: err actually its not :-x

Comment: is there something i need to do besides restart the brunch server to get config changes to take affect?

Comment: Is it `namespace.coffee` or `namespace.js`? Have you included it in `app/assets/index.html`?

Comment: its namespace.coffee - I would like it to be coffeescript.  I added `<script src="javascripts/namespace.js"></script>` to the `assets/index.html`

Comment: Files in `public/javascripts` should all be plain Javascripts, since they are created as the result of coffeescript compilation.

Comment: right, the problem is that's not happening.  For whatever reason the /^gator/ regex doesn't seem to be matching anything, `./public/javascripts/namespace.js` is not being created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't work. Brunch currently only watches top-level `app`, `vendor` and `test`. I think i'll change this in future release.

But you can do this:

```
joinTo:
  'javascripts/namespace.js': /^app(\/|\\)namespace/  # Only app/ns
  'javascripts/app.js': /^app(\/|\\)(?!namespace)/    # Everything but not app/ns
  'javascripts/vendor.js': /^vendor/
```

Comment: this works, what all those (\/|\\)(?! means? isn't an easy way? :D What if I want more than 1 namespace? say jquery and bootstrap. I currently have this : `'scripts/jquery.js': /^bower_components(\/|\\)jquery/`
           

 `'scripts/lib.js': /^(vendor|bower_components)(\/|\\)(?!jquery)/`